# Formula to flatten array of grid with negative values

Tags: c#, arrays, math, graph, formula

currently I am using this formula to flatten a multidimensional array (x,y,z):

```
    array = new byte[GridSizeX*GridSizeY*GridSizeZ];

    index = x + y * GridSizeX+ z * GridSizeX* GridSizeY;
```

I was wondering how I would go about making it work for negative values of either x,y and z, since the index can't be a negative value the formula doesn't work for example with the cell (-1,2,3).

Is there a clean formula that can take into account various ranges of x,y,z(also non uniform ranges)?

For example minX=-5, maxX =7/ minY=-2,maxY=3 // minZ=-4,maxZ =6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

`x` is in `[minX..maxX]` range

`y` is in `[minY..maxY]` range

`z` is in `[minZ..maxZ]` range

The formula for *zero-based* `index` will be

```
index = (x - minX) + 
        (y - minY) * (maxX - minX + 1) +
        (z - minZ) * (maxX - minX + 1) * (maxY - minY + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! Just for clarification the minX would be a negative value and not an absolute value, correct?

Comment: @fabrialis: `minX` as well as `minY`, `maxZ` etc. can be any value, either positive or negative

Comment: thanks! and for array size: (maxX - minX + 1)*(maxY - minY + 1)*(maxZ - minZ + 1) ?

Comment: @fabrialis: quite right, array size is `(maxX-minX+1)*(maxY-minY+1)*(maxZ-minZ+1)`